# Sum of powers mod $p^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have to prove this congruence mod $p^2$, I only require a good hint as opposed to a full solution.
$$\mathcal{S}_{m}(p^2) \equiv  \begin{cases}0& if\ (p-1)\nmid m\\-p & if\ (p-1)|m\end{cases}$$
where $\mathcal{S}_{m}(n):=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}k^{m}$.

The method I have tried so far is letting $g$ be a primitive root mod $p^{2}$ and observing that for $m\geq2$ (I directly verified the congruence for $m=1$) $p|k\Rightarrow p^2|k^m$, so that any $k$ in the sum not coprime to $p^2$ becomes $0$ so we get $$\mathcal{S}_{m}(p^2)\equiv\sum\limits_{l=0}^{p(p-1)-1} g^{ml}\ mod\ p^{2}.$$ Then after using the formula for a geometric sum and multiplying by $(g^{m}-1)$ I obtain $(g^{m}-1)\mathcal{S}_{m}(p^{2})\equiv g^{p(p-1)}-1\equiv 0\ mod\ p^{2}.$ It is at this point I am stuck, I am not sure how to use the divisibility conditions on $m$ and the congruence above to force $\mathcal{S}_{m}(p^2)$ to take the values I need, the main sticking point seems to be the presence of nontrivial zero-divisors in $\mathbb{Z}/(p^2)$. It's possible this may be a completely wrong method for this problem, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well certainly this would run into problems because multiplying by $(g^{m}-1)$ for $m$ a multiple of $p-1$ would not be reversible.  But $g^{p-1}$ is still a generator for the multiplicative subgroup of residues that are congruent to 1 modulo p

Answer (score 0):

Let us take your result

$$(g^m-1)\mathcal S_m(p^2)=0\pmod{p^2}$$

If $\;(p-1)\,\nmid\,m\;$ then $\;g^m\neq1\;$ (why?) and thus $\;\mathcal S_m(p^2)=0\pmod{p^2}\;$, and if

$$m=k(p-1)\implies g^{ml}=\left(g^{p-1}\right)^{kl}=1\implies$$

$$\sum_{l=0}^{p^2-p-1}g^{m}=p^2-p=-p\pmod{p^2}$$

Comment: Two things: I get why $(p-1)\nmid m\Rightarrow g^{m}\neq1$ but why does that automatically mean $\mathcal{S}_{m}(p^2)=0$ couldn't $(g^{m}-1)=p=\mathcal{S}_{m}(p^2)$ and if $g$ is a primitive root mod $p^2$ why is $(g^{p-1})^{kl}=1$ when surely $p(p-1)$ is the smallest $r$ such that $g^{r}=1$, sorry if I am missing something really obvious here.